# Image Resizer and ASP.NET Core

Tags: imageresizer

Can ImageResizer be used in an MVC6 (MVC Core) application. We understand that ImageFlow can be (not yet released), but what can we do in the meantime.
Many thanks

Comment: I also want to know if the current version of Image Resizer can be used in ASP.NET Core projects.

Comment: It seems Imageresizer people are not very interested even after 2 weeks. May be we should change to ImageProcessor?

Answer (score 5):

Imageflow.NET Server is the .NET Core equivalent to ImageResizer, but is much faster and produces much smaller image files. See https://github.com/imazen/imageflow-dotnet-server

If you want to do your own middleware, use Imageflow.NET directly. 
See https://github.com/imazen/imageflow-dotnet

Comment: Is there a nuget package for ImageFlow?  I only see Imazen.SlimResponse and Imazen.Webp, which don't look like the right packages.

Comment: There's not yet a C# wrapper for imageflow, thus no nuget package.

Comment: There is now a C# wrapper for Imageflow, named Imageflow.Net on NuGet.

Answer (score 2):

> I know this question is old as my grandpa but:

You can use this library,
this is in my Repo so I don't know should I recommend it or not,
but its exactly what you need,

**ImageFlow** after all these years still in RC mode 
so
I build it myself

https://github.com/keyone2693/ImageResizer.AspNetCore

Comment: Recommending a solution from your own website/blog/repo is fine, so long as you clearly state your association - which you have done.

Comment: This solution will not be anywhere near as performant as the official ImageResizer and the name is misleading.

Comment: @keyone2693 Why don't you commercialize it and make a killing. It looks like the other one (ImageFlow) will never see the light.

Comment: @user2981411 I am working on a watermark and disk cache to be added soon. and no plan for earning money just want to help

Comment: I agree you should change the name of this repo - it's extremely disingenuous.